# Metric disappeared - metadata.user_labels.name

Tags: stackdriver

I had few chart in a dashboard in Stackdriver.

This graph were about CPU / Disk IO etc..

The metrics was filtered using **metadata.user_labels.name**.

Everything worked fine until 2019-10-12T01:57:00Z. After that time no more metrics were displayed.

Changing filter using **metadata.system_labels.name** returned the Charts to normal state.

Why has this attribute disappeared?

**Update**

Using metrics explorer this parameters have data before 2019-10-12T01:57:00Z.

- Resource Type: GCE VM Instance
- Metric: CPU Load(1m) agent.googleapis.com/cpu/load_1m
- Filter: **name ( metadata.user_labels.name )**

This parameters have data for the whole period

- Resource Type: GCE VM Instance
- Metric: CPU Load(1m) agent.googleapis.com/cpu/load_1m
- Filter: **name ( metadata.system_labels.name )**

The problem affected all the instances (about 30) in the project and all the metrics.

No updates to operating system or configurations were made.

[image: Filtes]

In this image we can see that for the same instance **aem-prod-dispatcher-2** we have data up to 2019-10-12T01:57:00Z with the first set of parameters (brown line), while we have data for the whole period with the second set (blue line)

[image: Stackdriver Metrics Explorer]

Comment: Could you be more specific using exact resource type,metric, grouped by & charts you've configured?

Comment: I've added some detail. Thank you for you attention.

Comment: As you know, metadata.user_labels.name would only be present if the user sets the name tag on their instance — it's not there by default. But you mentioned “metadata.user_labels.name” was working before, I would suggest you to file an issue on Google's [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). This will bring the issue to the attention of Google.

Comment: Thank you Digil, I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: Reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142795335